Mean energy measurement in an arbitrary quantum state
I've gone through many papers looking for a way to measure a mean energy in an arbitrary state $\langle \psi | H | \psi \rangle$. I am interested in a theoretical protocol or an exemplary experimental procedure of performing such a measurement. Unfortunately I could not find anything.
The background of the problem is that I have an unknown time independent Hamiltonian and I need to measure a mean energy in, e.g. $| 1 0 0 \rangle $ state where 1 and 0 could correspond to a spin down/up state or any other degree of freedom that takes part in the interaction.
The responses I got already were based on the experimental reconstruction of the eigensystem and calculating the mean energy afterwards. This sadly does not help, as I still want the Hamiltonian to remain unknown. Does anyone have an idea how to do that?
I would be extremely grateful for any answer, even the one saying it's impossible.

Are you asking how to measure the energy of a quantum mechanical state at all? Or is there something more?

I think that I'm asking something more. In general measuring the eigenenergies, e.g. spectrum of a molecule, is not a problem. What I'm asking is how do measure energy in a state that you "force" your object to be.

But the energy is just another observable, like position. If I measure the position of a quantum particle, that particle is in some state $\psi$ before I measure it. And if I prepare a bunch of identical systems and measure a bunch of times, I will get results distributed according to $|\psi(x)|^2$, and the mean value of the quantity is the mean of that distribution. Right?

Right. For me the position, momenta, magnetisation etc. is clear. Also, the entire thing is almost trivial on paper. But still, after many years of working in physics, I don't have a clear understanding of any (even idealistic) way how to perform this task of the energy measurement experimentally.
